# How can I change the word in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, languages

I wrote the following command for the bibliography:

```
@MastersThesis{Bod:Thesis:2009, 
author = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Esther Bod}}, 
title = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Hilbert's tenth problem and some generalizations}}, 
school = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Utrecht University}}, 
address = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Netherlands}}, 
year = {2009}, 
}
```

The ouput is the following:

[image]

How can I change the word Μαστερ'ς τησις either in a greek word or this in english letters Masters Thesis ?

EDIT:

Adding the key langid=english and the biblatex option autolang=other I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Could we have a minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: Add `type={\foreignlanguage{english}{Master's Thesis}}` or `type={<Greek equivalent>}`

Comment: You should not have the language code in the bib file. Add the key `langid=english` and use the biblatex option `autolang=other.`

Comment: I added this command and now it works!! Thank you!! :-) @egreg

Answer (score 2):

Using biblatex, you should not enter LaTeX commands into the bib file, use biblatex's settings and options to handle things.

If you want that bib items are set in their respective language, add the `langid` field to the bib entry and use the biblatex option `autolang=other`.

Here an example with english and german, note that the main language is german but it says 'MA Thesis'  and not 'Magisterarbeit' in the bibliography. Also the quotes are different.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@MastersThesis{Bod:Thesis:2009,
  author = {Esther Bod},
  title = {Hilbert's tenth problem and some generalizations},
  school = {Utrecht University},
  address = {Netherlands},
  year = {2009},
  langid = {english},
}
@article{einstein,
  author = {Albert Einstein},
  title = {Ueber einen die Erzeugung und Verwandlung
           des Lichtes betreffenden heuristischen Gesichtspunkt},
  year = {1905},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  langid = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}


\cite{einstein}, \cite{Bod:Thesis:2009}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Result

after `pdflatex document.tex`, `biber document.bcf`, `pdflatex document.tex`:

[image: result]

## Change bibiliography strings

If you want to change the words in certain languages, you can use
`\DefineBibliographyStrings{<language>}{key=value}`

So if you wanted to change the greek name for the master thesis you would do:
`\DefineBibliographyStrings{greek}{mathesis={{new name}}}`

Comment: So I write this in the file main.tex and I don't create a new file mybibliography.bib, right? I tried this but I got an error... I added the message I get at my initial post... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: No,  this is just for demo purposes,  sorry.  In a regular document you would use a separate bib file.